# The only natural transformation $\text{id}_\mathsf{Ring}\to\text{id}_\mathsf{Ring}$ is the identity

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory, natural-transformations

I want to show that for any natural transformation $\eta:\text{id}_\mathsf{Ring}\to\text{id}_\mathsf{Ring}$ we have that $\eta_R=\text{id}_R$ for all $R\in\text{ob}(\mathsf{Ring})$.

I was able to show that in $\mathsf{Grp}$ there are only two natural transformations  $\text{id}_\mathsf{Grp}\to\text{id}_\mathsf{Grp}$ (the identity and the zero morphisms) by showing that group homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}\to G$ are in bijection with elements of $G$ so $\eta_G(g)=\eta_\mathbb{Z}(1)g$ for all $G$, and this is a group homomorphism for non-abelian groups if and only if $\eta_\mathbb{Z}(1)=0,1$.

I tried to do something similar with rings, but $\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't work and I am not sure which ring to use instead. Is this the right approach or is there a better way?
I'm looking for a hint rather than a full solution

Comment: The ring with the corresponding property is the polynomial ring $\mathbb Z[x]$. You can try using that.

Comment: @Wojowu Wow that was quick :) Thank you

Comment: @Wojowu So for each $r\in R$ I have $f_r:\mathbb{Z}[X]\to R$ given by $f_r(X)=r$. If we denote the polynomial $\eta_{\mathbb{Z}[X]}(x)$ by $p(x)$ then we have that $\eta_R(r)=f_r(\eta_{\mathbb{Z}[X]}(x))=p(r)$, but now I am not sure how to show $p(r)=r$

Comment: Look at the condition $ p(r)p(s) = p(rs) $ for two possibly non-commuting elements of $R$.

Comment: Hint: it suffices to show $p(x)=x$ for $R=\mathbb Z[x]$, For that take $R=\mathbb Z[x]$ and compute $\eta_{\mathbb Z}[x](f_r(x))$ for $r\in\mathbb Z[x]$.